# volatile vs. compiler barrier with gcc inline assembly

Tags: gcc, constraints, inline-assembly

In our product we have an inlined mutex implementation, using a variety of platform and compiler specific methods for the hardware specific parts.  One of our "rules" for some over-optimized code that attempts to "cheat", is that if a variable is accessed outside of the mutex and within, then that variable must be declared volatile.  I figured this applied to opaque mutex implementations too (such as pthread_mutex_lock/unlock), and this led to an interesting debate.

It's been asserted by one person that this is an indication of a compiler bug (especially when the mutex implementation is inlined and "not opaque" to the compiler).  I gave the following example to dispute this

```
int v = pSharedMem->myVariable ;

__asm__ __volatile__(( "isync" : : :"memory" ))

v = pSharedMem->myVariable ;
```

In this LinuxPPC gcc code fragment, the compiler doesn't have any knowledge of the run time effects of the isync, other than what we can tell it via the memory constraint.  You'd find such an isync instruction at the tail end of a mutex acquision to prevent any execution of the instructions that follow the successful acquire of the mutex before the mutex was actually held (so if a load had been executed before the isync it would have to be discarded).

In this code fragment, we have the compiler barrier that prevents a rewrite of the code as if it were the following

```
int v = pSharedMem->myVariable ;
v = pSharedMem->myVariable ;

__asm__ __volatile__(( "isync" : : :"memory" ))
```

or

```
__asm__ __volatile__(( "isync" : : :"memory" ))

int v = pSharedMem->myVariable ;
v = pSharedMem->myVariable ;
```

(ie: both of these compiler re-orderings should be inhibited by the **volatile** attribute)

We also have the isync itself that prevents the first reordering at run time (but I don't think prevents the second which isn't as interesting).

However, my question is that if myVariable is *not* declared volatile, whether or not the "memory" constraint is sufficient that gcc would necessarily re-load "v" after the isync?  I'd still be inclined to mandate volatile for such a pattern since this sort of code is too touchy with all the platform specific compiler builtins.  That said, if we reduce the discussion to just GCC and this code fragment, is this asm memory constraint enough to have code that is generated with a pair of loads instead of just one?

Answer (score 3):

The `__asm__ __volatile__` with `"memory"` clobber is required to and will act as full reordering barrier. `volatile` on the variable is unnecessary. In fact if you look at Linux kernel definition of [atomic_t](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.39/include/linux/types.h#L214), it does not use any `volatile` modifiers and relies completely on the `__asm__ __volatile__` statements with appropriate constraits.

On the other hand, I believe `volatile` on it's own does not in fact prohibit reordering at all, only caching and optimizing the value away altogether, so it's worthless for synchronization purposes.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not talking about volatile on the atomic or lock word, but on the data protected by the mutex.  I'm also not implying that the volatile has any synchronization value (ie: the synchronization is provided by the mutex and I'm wondering about data that is protected by the mutex).  If data is also accessed outside of the mutex, is volatile required to force the value to be reloaded once the mutex is acquired.

Comment: Here's some additional context (the original discussion that generated this question)


http://peeterjoot.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/an-unusual-volatile-required-example/

Comment: @Peeter: I am almost certain the sample there is wrong. Any non-inlined function call always forces re-fetch of non-local data from memory, because the compiler can't be sure the function does not have simple pointer to that data and simply write it, which can happen in single-threaded case and there the semantics is defined. On the other hand that code is incorrect with or without volatile, because reads are not atomic on some platforms. You need to use special synchronized atomic operations when accessing shared variables without locking.

Comment: @Jan, you're right about the need to re-fetch after calling non-inlined code, but in this case there's only a non-aliased local variable "v" being referenced, and I think as far as being sure its value is always "refreshed", Peeter is right in saying the compiler barrier is not enough. I too think you have to volatile-qualify the source of the data that gets captured in the "v" local